# Macbook Pro screen display problems

Tags: display, screen, gpu, cpu

I am using a Macbook Pro (the 2015 model A 1398).

Just overnight my screen shows strange horizontal lines as this:

[image]

**These horizontal lines are roughly gathered in the same place on the screen (on the top), and they may increase or decrease the numbers, from time to time.**

However, if I do the print screenshot, I do not see any such horizontal lines.
[image]

I did not hit or hurt my Macbook Pro recently. Can someone give any advice on how to fix it? I had restarted, shut down and restart a few times, but the problem still persists.

Info:
[image]

Thanks experts for the help!

Comment: There's dozens of questions and answers on this site about horizontal lines on retina screens.  Have you searched for them and tried the solutions that worked for other people?

Comment: I had tried this one -- but it does not work. "Command (⌘), Option, P, and R" seems not work for me...

Comment: In my experience this is a sign of the graphics card failing. Can you find out the temperature of the graphics card using a 3rd party app?

Comment: p.s. I tried this one and it does not work. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98569/coloured-vertical-lines-on-screen

Comment: I also tried to connect to another LCD projector (like giving a seminar talk), then the screen output for LCD projector has no those lines

Comment: @ Christian, indeed, what if the temperature is high -- just turn it off for a while and it will be fixed?

Comment: Horizontal lines are generally a symptom of hardware failure, either the GPU, display connection, or even something as general as a bad logic board. If you have AppleCare or are under warranty, I would get it serviced. If not under warranty, you'll likely still have to go through Apple for repair, but at a much greater cost.

Comment: Specifically, which MacBook Pro do you have?  There's one with Integrated Graphics (Intel Iris) and Discrete Graphics (Radeon R9).  Also, I would run [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.  Finally, to determine if it's your graphics, try running something like [ShibuyaCrowd](http://shibuyacrowd.mattatz.org/) to "stress" the GPU

Comment: Thanks guys --- I have Intel Iris Pro 1538 Mb. The Macbook pro info updated as above figure file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a 2015 MacBook Pro that uses *Integrated Graphics* (the Intel Iris Pro chipset), you can be assured that what is manifested on one screen, will manifest on all.

What this means is that the lines you are seeing on the screen ***are not*** due to failing GPU but rather the LCD itself.  You confirmed this by plugging your MBP into an *alternate* display device (projector).

If you have this under Apple Care, you should take it in to have it repaired straight away.  To fix this, you will need to replace the entire [Display Assembly](http://radnex.us/mbp-2015-retina-display-15) and unfortunately, they are very expensive (approx. $850USD).