# Growing black portion on the screen of 2017 MacBook Pro. What could be the cause?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware, repair

I bought my **MBP 13" 2017 (without TouchBar)** in late 2018. So far, so good, but after I started using it by plugging in an **LG 23" monitor** (as a second display), a black pixel stripe started showing up at the bottom of the screen on the MBP Retina display (even with when unplugged to the LG monitor) and its grown larger ever since. The Mac is out of warranty, so the only way would be to replace the entire screen assembly. Would this solve this issue? I'm guessing that using a MBP that doesn't have a graphics card with a second monitor is not a good idea...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That definitely looks like a screen (LCD) issue.  Whether  it's on the MacBook or it's the LG, the screen is damaged and must be replaced. However, I'm assuming it's the screen on your Mac...

> The Mac is out of warranty, so the only way would be to replace the entire screen assembly.

Yes.  You would be correct; the only way would be to replace the screen assembly.

- [Macbook Pro screen display problems](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/319688/macbook-pro-screen-display-problems/319728#319728)
- [Part of display not working, changing display region for macbook pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382230/part-of-display-not-working-changing-display-region-for-macbook-pro/382233#382233)

> I'm guessing that using a MBP that doesn't have a graphics card with a second monitor is not a good idea

Connecting an external monitor to a laptop (not limited to Macs as PCs use the same Intel processors) that has a port specifically to do that wouldn't cause any damage whatsoever to your laptop.

Damage happens and it could be from any number of reasons - a manufacturing defect to physical impact with something.  But most definitely, it's not because you connected an external LCD to your Mac.

Comment: I see, but do you think I might try to change the whole display assembly rightaway? On the above comment was mentioned that it could be an issue with the flex cable and I read that also on a Discord channel. Since it is much cheaper than the whole display, might be worth the risk?

Comment: @RodrigoMiranda flex assemblies are basically disposable, they are very delicate so you can certainly try that, but you can’t return them and you’ll almost certainly need a new display. If cost is a factor, I would save your repair dollars and run in closed clamshell mode. Send it in for a flate rate repair once something else fails and you’ll get a rebuilt Mac for about 700 at that point.

Comment: Don’t flex the screen since this is caused by the glass and crystal separating from delicate wiring on the edge. If the frame is flexing, this will progress as the screen flexes further and further and eventually fail totally. LVDS cables affect all the signal, not just a band horizontally

Comment: @bmike is correct.  It’s not the flex cable and is the LCD assembly.  The flex cable usually manifests as the display failing once you open it past a certain point, then the *whole* display fails. A dead spot that grows is the screen.

Comment: @bmike@Allan I see, so I should probably replace the whole display assembly then. Found this one on eBay and seems to look fine, it's the right one for this model (A1708):

https://www.ebay.com/itm/923-01288-Apple-Display-Flex-Cable-MPXQ2LL-A-A1708-MACBOOK-PRO-13-INCH-2017/153868643007?epid=4016071718&hash=item23d3492abf:g:uYYAAOSwCEhecT9N

Comment: Assuming that your model numbers are correct, that looks like the right flex, but I doubt it’ll fix the issue, but it can’t hurt

Comment: @Allan sorry, I sent the wrong link lol, I meant the one for the display assembly:

https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0825TGNR3/?coliid=I26TRC2E0CC3UA&colid=1QRN3MP4J82FF&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it

https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Retina-Late-2016-2017-Display-Assembly/IF123-066?o=3